# Chef loop doesn't execute when resource is notified by another resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm writing a chef recipe to install Splunk on an ec2 instance.  I only want to install Splunk on the initial setup of the instance.  The recipe doesn't need to run a second time.

I'm using notifications to only execute subsequent blocks of code if conditions are met:

```
#install splunk
dpkg_package 'splunkforwarder' do
    source '/tmp/splunkforwarder.deb'
    action :nothing
    notifies :run, 'execute[configure-splunk]', :immediately
end
```

Here is the block that is notified

```
commands = ['command1', 'command2', 'etc']
commands.each do |i|
    execute "configure-splunk" do
        command i
        action :nothing
    end
end
```

The issue is that when 'configure-splunk' is called, it only seems to run the last command in the list instead of looping through all of the commands.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, when you have multiple resources with same name+type pair, only the last one is available when you look up for that name.

What you probably want is:

```
execute "configure-splunk" do
    command commands.join(' && ')
    action :nothing
end
```

Comment: Why is that?  It seems that a loop should evaluate all items in a list regardless of the content of the items?

Comment: It's not the loop, it's the `notifies :run, 'execute[configure-splunk]'`. When you have colliding names, Chef picks the most recent resource that was added with that name as the one to receive the notification.